# Why the returned entity from saveAndFlush() has its OneToMany fields mapped to null?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I have the following entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_LABEL")
public class Label {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String caption;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "label", fetch = FetchType.EAGER , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PartLabel> parts;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "label_parts")
public class PartLabel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "LABEL_PART_ID")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "LABEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "LABEL_ID", nullable = false)
    private Label label;
}
```

and Repository

```
public interface LabelRepository extends JpaRepository<Label, Long> {

}
```

**My question is why in the following piece of code**

**the set 'parts' in selectedLabel is mapped correctly**

**but the set 'parts' in updatedLabel is mapped to null although the DB is updated fine**

```
        Label selectedLabel =labelRepository.findById(2L).get();
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setId(2L);
        label.setCaption("any caption");
        Label updatedLabel = labelRepository.saveAndFlush(label);
```

Comment: I believe there is something missing in your code example. There is nowhere a set parts call.

Comment: when i call `findById(2L).get()` the relation *OneToMany* does it's part so the set is retrieved,  when I call `labelRepository.saveAndFlush(label)` I am guessing that `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`  should do so

Comment: Ah now I see what you are doing. Well what do you think will happen when you save your updated Label with an empty parts list and an CascadeType.ALL ? It deletes your parts, so no wonder it is now emtpy. If you want to update your caption set it on the selectedLabel. As long as it is managed you don´t have to save it, as it will get updated by the transactional write behind mechanism itself.